# Complex ActiveRecord joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a table called `invoices`, and `invoices` `belongs_to :subscription`, and `subscription` `belongs_to :user`. A `user` `has_many :licenses`. I need two queries, one gets all the `invoices` that had `licenses` created during a specific time period, such that those `licenses` do not have a specific `viewership_id`.

I was able to get that query correct, here it is:

```
Invoice.joins(
  subscription: { 
    user: :licenses 
  } 
).where(
  # Other licenses during date range
  licenses: { 
    created_at: date_range
  }
).where.not(
  licenses: {
    viewership_id: Viewership.member.tier(1).first.id
  }
)
```

Now, I need a query that gets all the `invoices` that did not have any licenses created during a specific time period. Something like this (though this doesn't work):

```
Invoice.includes(
    subscription: { 
      user: :licenses 
    } 
  ).where(
    licenses: { 
      user_id: nil,
      created_at: date_range # <-- removing this works, but is an incorrect query, 
                             # because the user may have created other 
                             # licenses outside of this date_range and 
                             # that's alright--so querying without the 
                             # date_range means i may miss some users who 
                             # have licenses that just weren't created in 
                             # the date_range
    }
  )
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what you want exactly especially with that comment. It might help if you can create a little visual table of licenses which shows what you are trying to achieve. I'm also a bit puzzled - if you want is  licenses why don't you start the query from Licence?

Comment: @max I said I need number of invoices, not licenses. I'll try to write up a diagram

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Have you considered setting up a less tangential relation between Invoice and Licence? The fact that you are joining 3 tables down seems like a real code smell besides being slow.

Comment: @max no problem. I would definitely do that in a normal use case, but in this instance it's only run once a month for reporting purposes, so speed isn't important and it would be quite a headache to keep invoices synced to licenses because there may be instances where an invoice comes in and a license was created before it got there. Invoices are generated through webhooks from stripe

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you

```
# Create a date range
from_date = 1.months.ago 
to_date = Time.now

@invoices = Invoice.joins(subscription: [user: :licenses]).where("licenses.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ? AND licenses.viewership_id !=?", from_date, to_date, Viewership.member.tier(1).first.id)
```

For getting all the `invoices` that did not have any licenses created during a specific time period.

```
@invoices = Invoice.includes(subscription: [user: :licenses]).where("licenses.created_at NOT BETWEEN ? AND ?", from_date, to_date)
```

Comment: That's the query I already had correct, the second query I listed was the one I can't get right. Thanks tho

Comment: Ohh...My bad. In that case you can search `Invoices` by `licenses.created_at` not between given date range. I update the answer.

Comment: That query will see if it doesn't have any licenses created during that period, but it won't check to see if it doesn't have any licenses at all. I need to find those that either don't have any licenses at all, or have some that weren't created between those dates